# How to create specific error messages based on parse exceptions in JavaCC

Tags: java, javacc, parseexception

I'm making a JavaCC program to accept a certain language. I've done this but cannot understand how to use a generated ParseException to determine the issue in the input, and customise the output error message.

So far my code looks like:

```
try {
  task parser = new task(System.in);
  parser.start();
  System.out.println("YES"); // If accepted print YES.
} catch (ParseException e) {
  System.out.println("NO"); // If rejected print NO.
  switch (e) {
    case 1:
       System.err.println("Some error case")
    case 2:
       ...
  }  
}
```

Some sources I've looked at are the documentation for ParseException and the JavaCC error handling pages. Neither have helped me understand much better.

If anyone could help/hint I would be really thankful.

Comment: The usual thing to do is something like `System.err.println( e.getMessage() )`. Are these messages are not good enough for your application?

Comment: Unfortunately not - that was actually another question I was going to ask in the near future! I have to specify exactly why the string wasn't accepted (a trivial example being the length of the string is incorrect).

Comment: As for this question though, does my code look correct for this type of error? I'm admittedly not very good at error handling. I imagine it shouldn't be `switch (e)` - maybe `switch (e.getPosition())`? Additionally, does the method that contains this code need to `throws ParseException`, or does the `try...catch` not require this?

Comment: The code in your question does not throw a ParseException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always throw a `ParseException` with a custom string.  For example

```
void Primary() : {}
{
    <INT> 
|
    "("
|
     {throw new ParseException("At "+getCoords()
                              +" there was \""+ getToken(1).image
                              + "\", but the parser expected either"
                              + " a \"(\" or an integer literal.");}
}
```

If you are willing to go to enough effort, it should be possible to create a parser that never throws a `ParseException` that doesn't have a custom message.

Comment: Does this still work? I get ```error: cannot find symbol
{if (true) throw new ParseException("At " + getCoords()
                                            ^
  symbol:   method getCoords()
```

Comment: For this to work you need to define the getCoords() method in the parser class.  It needs to produce a string or object that formats the current coordinates appropriately.